# regular expression to remove specific anchor tags

Tags: php, html, regex, dreamweaver

I have a HUGE HTML file that has around 300 instances of similar anchor tag that need removing

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:thumbs(198, 0, 'architecture')" class="icon"></a>
```

this issue is that the section

```
javascript:thumbs(198, 0 '
```

can  have any number between 1 and 999 and the second inumber is the same, I tried:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:thumbs([1-9]?[1-9]?[1-9], [0-9]?[0-9], 'architecture')" class="icon"></a>
```

(this is a reg replace in dreamweaver btw) and it says there are no instances, I have tried many variations of the number reg and its not hitting the mark, could someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: You are missing the comma and the space...

Comment: Sorry I typed it with the comma and space missing, I will edit to reflect the right use, the regex I used had the comma and the space, but thanks for the quick reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it right, you would like the regex to match your specific tags in dreamweaver... You could try this:

```
<a href="javascript:void\(0\);" onclick="javascript:thumbs\([0-9]{0,2}[0-9], [0-9]?[0-9], 'architecture'\)" class="icon"><\/a>
```

Example: http://regex101.com/r/hJ0cE9/1

Basically, the difference with your regex is escaping special characters (e.g. instead of `(`, put `\(`), and adding a comma after your second number pattern.

Comment: I originally Put 'Regex Gives me a headache! and this is why I hate it so much!' but someone edited my question and deleted it, without even saying why, which, when its my question I thought was a bit rude